# How can I convert this string representing a Date into an ISO 8601 compliant using JS?

Tags: javascript, rhino, iso8601

I am not so into JavaScript and I have the following problem.

I have a **JSON** object like this:

```
{
    "start_date": "2017-11-09 06:00:00"
}
```

Into a JavaScript script executed into the browser I do:

```
var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date(currentOriginalForecast.start_date);
```

and it works fine: it creates a new Date object with the value related to **2017-11-09 06:00:00** date.

The problem is that I have to perform this JavaScript script into a Java application using **Rhino** (a JavaScript implementation that allows to perform JS code into a Java application) and here it cause an error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-09 11:10:08,915]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext} -  dateCurrentOriginalForecast: Invalid Date {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-09 11:10:08,918] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} -  The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: RangeError: Date is invalid. (<Unknown Source>#137) in <Unknown Source> at line number 137
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
```

It seems that this date is invalid and it can't create the **Date** object.

From what I understood reading online the problem should be that old JS or Rhino (maybe the version of JS implemented by Rhino) does not support date of this type and probably I have to convert it in a date format which is fully compliant with **ISO 8601**

So I think that I have to convert my string **2017-11-09 06:00:00** into something like compliant with **ISO 8601** standard.

I can't use third party library.

How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried with `'2017-11-09T06:00:00'` or `'2017-11-09T06:00:00T'`? maybe its just the missing `T` and/or `Z`. in JS it works in all three versions correctly.

Comment: I am not sure about what you need. Is it how to generate an ISO8601 date in javascritp or something different?

Comment: @NinaScholz What do you exactly mean? What have I to try to do?

Comment: just test with the two string and look if that works.

Comment: @NinaScholz I tryied both: var dateCurrentOriginalForecastISO8601 = new Date('2017-11-09T06:00:00'); and var dateCurrentOriginalForecastISO8601 = new Date('2017-11-09T06:00:00T'); but I still obtain the invalid date error message

Answer (score 0):

Can use `Date#toISOString()` or `Date#toJSON()`

```js
let d = new Date('2017-11-09 06:00:00')

console.log(d.toISOString())
console.log(d.toJSON())
```

Answer (score 0):

//if you want convert date without convert in timezone than

var date = '2017-11-09 06:00:00';
var convertDate =  date.replace(" ", "T"); // 2017-11-09T06:00:00

//if you want to convert in date with utc timezone
var date = new Date("2017-11-09 06:00:00").toISOString()

Comment: some browser in not working so attach date = date + ".000z"; for without convert date in utc timezone

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly the problem is not so much that you need a ISO 8601 formatted date, but it is that you need to create a `Date` object from a date that is not formatted in ISO 8601. I personally would just use regular expression to parse the date into it's parts and then pass them into the `Date` constructor:

```js
var currentOriginalForecast = {
    "start_date": "2017-11-09 06:00:00"
};

var rxParseDate = /(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s+(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/;
var dateParts = currentOriginalForecast.start_date.match(rxParseDate);

var year = dateParts[1],
  month = dateParts[2],
  day = dateParts[3],
  hour = dateParts[4],
  minute = dateParts[5],
  second = dateParts[6];

var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second));

console.log(dateCurrentOriginalForecast);
```

Since there is no timezone mentioned in the `start_date`, I'm assuming it is UTC and converting it using [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) and passing the resulting timestamp from that into the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor. If `start_date` is in local time you would just remove `Date.UTC` and pass the parameters directly into the `Date` constructor. I'll also mention the `month - 1`; that is because the `Date` constructor (and `Date.UTC`) expect a 0-based month.